# Eregi need replacement?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eregi

I got the following function while googling for bot behaviour. while i am using this code, i get error for `eregi()` expression. i am not an expert of regualar expression. since `ereri( )` has been depreciated, i am getting the same error.

```
 function check_if_spider()
        {
            // Add as many spiders you want in this array
            $spiders = array('Googlebot', 'Yammybot', 'Openbot', 'Yahoo', 'Slurp', 'msnbot', 'ia_archiver', 'Lycos', 'Scooter', 'AltaVista', 'Teoma', 'Gigabot', 'Googlebot-Mobile');

            // Loop through each spider and check if it appears in
            // the User Agent
            foreach ($spiders as $spider)
            {
                if (eregi($spider, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
```

how can i modify the code to make it workin? google search says it should be converted to `preg_match();` being a newbee, i am at failure, although i tried at my end..can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't actually using regular expressions (you're matching literal strings) so there's no need to use `preg_match()`.

Replace

```
if (eregi($spider, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
```

with

```
if (strpos($spider, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [strstr](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strstr.php) to compare strings.
It returns false if the string in the first parameter does not contain the string in the second parameter.

```
foreach ($spiders as $spider)
    {
        if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $spider))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```